# Validation in WebForms

Tags: .net, winforms, validation, webforms

I'm developing an intranet desktop application and most of functionality requires a web interface to go along with it. The desktop part for the first iteration is pretty much complete and now I have to do it in WebForms. I haven't touched WebForms in over a year and am wondering...

If I have a form with some textboxes, I realize I can code validation using javascript and whatnot but is there a way that I can do it like I can in WinForms? WinForms textboxes have a Validating method that is called when the user leaves the texbox. On the desktop app I have it rigged up to set the class instance property which has validation in the setting of the property. Is there a way I can do the same in WebForms or must I write it all out again on the client side? ASP TextBoxes have a textchanged method, but I don't see validating. I'm thinking you guys are going to say I have to write it all out again client-side, but here's to hoping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do it from scratch. Asp.Net has several built-in validators to assist with data types, range, comparison between fields, required fields, and even with a summary of the errors. [See this link for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwd43d0x.aspx)

You can also use your own javascript with this validation model using the [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) control.

w3schools.com has a really nice tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_refvalidationcontrols.asp)

**Edited:** Avoiding postbacks

You can wrap your TextBox with an UpdatePanel in order to use Ajax or if you want to make it more efficient you could use jQuery to call a WebMethod and set the object. Example:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]    
public static  string MyWebMethod(String someVar)
{ 
    HttpContext.Current.Session["someVar"] = someVar;
}
```

On the client side:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Page.aspx/MyWebMethod',
        data: "{ someVar: 'valueFromTextBox' }",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            //alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is it possible to set a c# object property when I leave a textbox with one of these validation controls?

Comment: I kind of found a way to do what I want to do using the TextChanged Event and AutoPostBack = True for the textbox. It does what I want but now I just have to figure out how to do it without causing a page refresh.

Comment: You can wrap your TextBox with an UpdatePanel in order to use Ajax or if you want to make it more efficient you could use jQuery to call a WebMethod and set the object.

Comment: Yeah I'm reading about the WebMethod with jQuery AJAX and it is exactly what I'm looking for. The only issue is that I declare a class object at form level but don't seem to have access to the object variable from within the WebMethod... If I can figure out how to access it then I'll be golden.

Comment: Just had to declare my variable as static and she works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well your comment resolved it, am I able to mark your comment as the answer? I've also switched from making the variable static to holding it in ViewState instead. I just have to create a new instance of the class inside the WebMethod and run it through the property validation depending on which textbox is passed into the method since I can't access my ViewState variable directly in the WebMethod which really sucks.

Comment: I'm the same author of the original response and the comment, I'll move the comment to the answer. Regarding the issue with the ViewState you could also try using the session (`HttpContext.Current.Session`) and adding `EnableSession = true` as parameter to the WebMethod attribute